# Windows 2000 WiFi Internet Access

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-2000

I am trying to configure an old laptop to connect tothe internet via a Buffalo USB Wi-Fi adapter.  Having installed allof the drivers & wi-fi management softwareI can connect to my router,and to a number of local un-secured networks successfully.  But when I start Internet Explorer I get the message "The page cannot be displayed".

Can anyone tell me what I have failed to do in Windows 2000?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you do not have a proxy configured in Internet Explorer. Also, make sure you successfully resolve DNS.

A few commands to try (and post the output here):

`ipconfig /all` - make sure you have a default gateway so you can route outside your LAN

`ping www.google.com` - make sure you can ping Google, if you can't:

`nslookup www.google.com` - tries to resolve Google's domain using your default DNS server, and bypasses Windows' DNS engine (so `hosts` does not make a difference here).